# Redirect to URI sends back the POSTed params added in browser's URL bar

Tags: grails

Grails Version: 3.3.4, 
Groovy Version: 2.4.14, 
JVM Version: 1.8.0_161, 
Kubuntu 14.04

I wrote a simple authentication form (in the end it will be POSTed through https):

```
<form action='auth' method='POST' id='loginForm' class='cssform' autocomplete='off'>
<p>
    <label for='j_username'>Login ID</label>
    <input type='text' class='text_' name='j_username' id='j_username' />
</p>
<p>
    <label for='j_password'>Password</label>
    <input type='password' class='text_' name='j_password' id='j_password' />
</p>
<p>
    <input type='submit' value='Login' />
</p>
```

The controller is:

```
class LoginController {

def index()  {
    if (session.user?.name == 'test') {
        render view: '/login/youarealreadyin'
    }
    else {
        render view: '/login/auth'
    }
}

def auth() {
    def loginName = params.j_username?.trim()
    def pass = params.j_password?.trim()

    if (loginName == 'test' && pass == 'TEST' ) {
        session.user = [name: loginName]
        redirect uri: '/'
    }
    else {
        render view: '/login/denied'
    }
}
```

}

After correct login and redirect to uri: '/' - I see the name and password in the URL field of the browser:

```
http://localhost:8080/?j_username=test&j_password=TEST
```

I could swear that this didn't happen with grails 3 in the first versions... I cannot remember when...

It would be nice, not to send back the POSTed password as GET params in the URL.

If I render a specific view instead to redirect it doesn't happen.

Comment: This is a known bug and is fixed in 3.3.5 - either downgrade to 3.3.2 or wait for 3.3.5 (should be this week) https://github.com/grails/grails-core/pull/10974

Comment: Erich, I didn't know that. Thanks. It's not an urgency. Waiting for 3.3.5 sounds good. If I'll ever be finishing, will have 5.5.5. So I'll ask from time to time some strange things ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are reporting this as undesired behavior, our GitHub issue tracker at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues is a better place to do that.  This has already been reported though at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10965 and it looks like the fix has been verified in 3.3.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT and looks good.

If you are simply asking if this is intended behavior, it isn't.

Comment: Thank you for the insight Jeff. I'm not a pro and to unexperienced to report my problems straight to the issue tracker. I've been first asking here because I wasn't able to discover myself, that'd be already known and fixed and that's really an issue. Thank you and all the team

Comment: "...to unexperienced to report my problems straight to the issue tracker" - I understand why you might be hesitant if you aren't 100% sure but don't be intimidated to file issues.  Being new doesn't preclude you from recognizing bugs or from having ideas for improvement.  All input is welcome!